# Proper syntax Match and If not isblank

Tags: excel-2016

I need to replace the data the agt_amt from the Billing worksheet with the value in the Adding of the  BalanceSheet.Difference to the Billing.Agt_Amt  when the Validated Adj = Y.  I have been playing with the Match and if not isblank formula but need some assistance with the proper syntax.

Restating problem
 I need to check if the value has been validated hence the Validate=Y, Then Adjust the value of the Billing.agt_amt by the value of the qryDifference.Differernce.

Say for Craig W his agent amt 195.75 and he has been validated to need and adjustment in the amount due (-5.50) to him. I need to adjust the agent amount to be 190.25 on the original Billing.

So I thought to create a new Column on the Billing worksheet with the adjusted value and the original value then copy the column over the original prior to finalizing the worksheet.

```
 =MATCH([@agtno],qryDifference[agtno],IF(NOT(ISBLANK(qryDifference[Validate Adjustment])),qryDifference[Difference],0))
```

Solution found Elsewhere:

```
=IF([@agtno]=B24,[@[agt_amt]],SUMPRODUCT((Balance!$B$2:$B$7=[@agtno])*(Balance!$F$2:$F$7="Y")*Balance!$E$2:$E$7)+[@[agt_amt]])
```

Comment: What is qryDifference?

Comment: name of my table based on a PowerQuery

Comment: If your fields are returning named ranges, please show some examples - of values returned from them. Also indicate if ranges are in same sheet. Is @agtno as parameter? Show example row from sheet

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about contents and using the table, but if you copied/pasted your formula you have a missing bracket

Try

```
=IF(not(ISBLANK(qryDifference[Validate Adjustment])),qryDifference[Difference])
```

Comment: How do I include this suggestion into the Match portion of the statement.  I need to be able to match agentIDs from both worksheets.

      =MATCH([@agtno],qryDifference[agtno],0)

Comment: Not clear what agentIDs you're referring to? You have four different fields you're using. IsBlank is checking `qryDifference[Validate Adjustment])` and showing `qryDifference[Difference]` if it's blank. Next statement is matching `[@agtno],qryDifference[agtno]`. Can you describe in words what you're actually trying to do

Comment: Sorry I meant @Agtno.,

I need to check if the value has been validated hence the Validate=Y, Then Adjust the value of the Billing.agt_amt by the value of the qryDifference.Differernce.  

Say for Craig M his agent amt 100 and he has been validated to need and adjustment in the amount due (5.50) to him.  I need to adjust the agent amount to be 105.50 on the original Billing.

Comment: So I thought to create a new Column on the Billing worksheet with the adjusted value and the original value then copy the column over the original prior to finalizing the worksheet

=MATCH([@agtno],qryDifference[agtno],IF(NOT(ISBLANK(qryDifference[Validate Adjustment])),qryDifference[Difference],0))

Comment: What is `[@agtno]` - is that a parameter the user has to type in - or does it come from a fixed cell? Does that formula you just suggested not work for you?

Comment: PLEASE NOTE:  I need to only change the first row per agent, since the agent can have many records.

Comment: the table has named ranges.

Comment: Perhaps you can go back to your original question and add some more details - the question has changed dramtically from an error with IsBlank. I have no idea what "first row only" or "named ranges" have to do with your original question. Possibly some screen shots would help.